# Come tradurre: submitter?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, translation, single-words

Come posso tradurre **submitter** in italiano?

Il contesto è un sito web dove devo tradurre *Submitter name*.
In questo si intende colui che ha inviato l'abstract.

Non saprei proprio come tradurlo.

Vorrei evitare di mettere: Nome di colui che ha inviato l'abstract :)

Ho trovato che viene usato a volte **richiedente**. Ma non mi sembra opportuno dato il contesto.

**Applicante** mi sembra l'unico utilizzabile. Ma si capisce cosa si intende?

Comment: “Applicante” è un calco tremendo (“applicare” in italiano non ha il significato di *to apply*); tanto varrebbe mettere “sottomettitore”. :-) “Proponente”, forse? Ora ci penso un altro po'.

Comment: Per il contesto che descrivi starei sul generico "utente" per evitare definizioni insolite.

Comment: "proponente" potrebbe andare bene

Comment: Visto che si tratta di un sito web dove i termini inglesi abbondano, perché non tenere "submitter"?

Comment: Ho lasciato dei termini inglesi come account e voucher per evitare di creare confusione. Però submitter sarebbe un po' forzato.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In un commento ipotizzavo **proponente**, ma forse è un po' generico.

Alla luce anche dei chiarimenti dell'OP nei commenti, potrebbe andare **mittente**? È un po' burocratico ma definisce specificamente “chi manda qualcosa”. O anche **responsabile dell'invio**.

Answer (score 2):

Io tradurrei **Autore**. Quando non è presente una traduzione immediata del termine, è meglio tradurre il concetto nel modo più rispondente possibile. Nel tuo caso, se si intende che *colui che ha inviato l'abstract* ne sia l'autore, la traduzione più corretta mi sembra questa.

Comment: Grazie per la risposta. Purtroppo non posso essere generico in questo caso. L'applicazione web è molto specifica. Per esempio differenzia tra Autore Presentatore e Autore non presentatore. In questo caso è richiesto in modo specifico colui che si è fatto carico dell'invio dell'abstract (assumendosene la responsabilità presumo).